# Structure of input to the function

Tags: python

I was trying to understand the structure of input(x).I know it is a dictionary but what kind of key ,value structures it holds for  the following function.Please help.

```
import functools
def row_func(x):
    datadict = {prefix+x[keyx]:x[valuex] for x in data}
    return datadict
    if 'unique_actions' in x and x['unique_actions']:
        x.update(get_flat(x['unique_actions'],'action_type','value','unique_actions'))

    if 'actions' in x and x['actions']:
        x.update(get_flat(x['actions'],'action_type','value','actions'))
    if 'action_values' in x and x['action_values']:
        x.update(get_flat(x['action_values'],'action_type','value','action_values'))

    f = [
        [('get','spend')],
        [('get','unique_clicks')],
        [('get',"impressions")],
        [('get',"placement")],
        [('get',"impression_device")],

        ]
    print tuple([functools.reduce(lambda k,y : getattr(k,y[0])(*y[1:]), op, x)  for op in f])
```

Comment: Why not just add a print statement? Plus, the code after the `return` statement is not reachable, i.e. not even the first `if` get executed...

Comment: Just replace the body of the function with `print(repr(x))`, that will give you a better idea. Or look at the documentation for... wherever it comes from. We can't tell you what keys and values it has.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the data type of the keys of x, you could fetch the list of keys with x.keys() and then use type() on the elements of the list, same for the values with x.values()